# in dataframe multicolumn elementwise operation (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

given a DataFrame df,  I would like to do something like:

```
if df['one'] >= df['two']:
    df['three'] = df['four']
    df['five'] = df['two'] / df['four']
```

Comment: I don't mind the down vote, but at least point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.loc` attribute with boolean indexing.

```
condition = df.one >= df.two
df.loc[condition, 'three'] = df['four']
df.loc[condition, 'five'] = df['two'] / df['four']
```

Comment: Clearly typing 90 wpm is just not fast enough anymore :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud You can take the next one ;)